# Usage of Intermediate Value Theorem in $n$ dimensions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a function such that $ f:U\subseteq  \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and path connected and $f$ is continuous. Let $x_1 , x_2 \in U$. Proof that for all $c \in [f(x_1),f(x_2)]$ there exists an $x \in U$ such that $f(x)=c$.
I'm supposed to use one-dimensional intermediate value theorem to proof this.
There is a hint stating that I should look out for a function $\varphi: [0,1] \rightarrow U $ such that we use a "useful" composition of $f$ and $\varphi$.
I really don't know how to do this proof I would appreciate help a lot!

Comment: Hint: Take $\varphi$ to be a path from $x_1$ to $x_2$.

Answer (score 1):

You could let $\phi$ be a continuous function satisfying $\phi(0) = x_1$ and $\phi(1) = x_2$. Its existence is guaranteed by path-connectedness. The composition $f \circ \phi$ is continuous, maps $[0,1]$ to $\mathbf R$, and satisfies $f\circ \phi(0) = f(x_1)$ and $f \circ \phi(1) = f(x_2)$. There must exist $t \in [0,1]$ with $f \circ \phi(t) = c$: what can you say about $\phi(t)$?

Comment: hmm I don't know where you're going by what about phi(t)

Comment: According to your question you need to find a point $x \in U$ satisfying $f(x) = c$. So far there is a point $t \in [0,1]$.

Comment: since phi is continuos there must be a b=phi(t) such that f(b)=c right?